# adb error : device not found

Tags: android, adb

Android ADB showing ***device not found*** error when trying to install Apk. 
After installing few apk's it becomes slow and disconnects all of a sudden giving adb device not found error. Please help me with a solution.

Comment: you are using emulator or real device?

Answer (score 0):

File-> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run

disable "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy(default enable)

Answer (score 0):

The information shared by you seems a bit generic, still you can try any of the following solutions.

1. Open command prompt as administrator and enter below commands:

   - "adb kill-server"
   - "adb start-server"
2. Install drivers for you phone if you're not testing on emulator.
3. Open android sdk manager and check/install "Google USB Driver" from extras folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows 7 and my adb driver was not working tried everything even google driver was showing error when i updated driver that it is not compatible with 32 bit. I tried changing cables and commands but it was showing exclamation mark on ADB interfaces in other devices inside device manager. Adb devices was also not showing any devices. I installed universal adb driver and now it is working fine. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try `adb start-server`

for my case,it started,and the device is listed below.

```bash
> adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Then a pop-up window will be displayed on the smartphone,click to continue.

Answer (score -1):

Probably won't work and you already have tried it, but if no one of the previous answers help, sometimes it's usb cable's fault. Just try an other one to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

I went to File-> Invalidate Cashes/Restart this fixed it for me